# How to query Django many-to-many relationship which has an intermediate model to handle the relationship?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

It is probably a very simple question but I did not manage to figure it out so far.

I have a many-to-many relationship in Django models like that:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    ...

class Category(models.Model):
    ...

class PostCategory(models.Model):
    """A connection class needed for other things to work.
    It is not possible to sily have the ParentalManyToMany field."""
    post = ParentalKey(
        'models.Post',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='categories',
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        'models.Category',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='posts',
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('post', 'category')
```

As mentioned in the class docstring, I cannot use simply ParentalManyToMany field due to other requirements.

Now my question is how to perform the following query.
Suppose I've selected some posts, e.g. `posts = Post.objects.filter(...)`, and I want to select all the categories for only these posts. How to perform such a query?

If I query `categories = Category.objects.filter(post__in=posts)`, I get the following error: `ValueError: Cannot query 'posts': Must be "PostCategory" instance.`

If I query `PostCategory.objects.filter(post__in=posts)`, I get obviously `PostCategory` queryset with `PostCategory` objects.

How do I now get from `PostCategory` objects queryset for the distinct `Category` objects?

Answer (score 0):

All right, I figured one way to do it.

```py
categories = Category.objects.filter(id__in=PostCategory.objects.filter(post__in=Post.objects.filter(...)).values('category__id').distinct())
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

To me, your `related_name` parameters are wrong.
Assuming the Post model has a M2M with Category, the `related_name` "posts" should be inside this M2M declaration.
Your PostCategory model should define "post_categories" as `related_name`.
If you do the above, what you first tried should work.

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(posts__id__in=my_posts.values_list("id", flat=True)).distinct()
```

Note that "post" in `posts__id__in` is the mentioned `related_name` if the M2M is in Post. If the M2M is declared in Category, it should be the name of the field.
`id__in=my_subquery.values_list("id", flat=True)` is the usual way to declare subquery that filter on id.
`.distinct()` is required because Django will perform a join between Category and PostCategory that will result in multiple entries for a single category if it has several Post attached